# Infinite descent method

Tags: secondary-education, proofs

We have plenty of examples in mathematical induction for advanced level mathematics students. Can we introduce infinite descent method as extremely opposite approach to mathematical induction and is it important to mention by the name infinite descent method when you prove irrationality of square root 2 by the method of contradiction rather than just mentioning method of contradiction ? 
What would you suggest as examples to apply infinite descent method such as proving non existence of positive integers $x,y,z$ satisfying the equation $x^3 + 2y^3 = 4z^3 $, which are not much complicated ?

Comment: Infinite descent method is a kind of proof by contradiction. Assume there's a smallest x, then I found a smaller one, therefore there's no x. It doesn't have much to do with induction.

Comment: @user253751 Actually, what you're describing sounds a lot like induction: assume that there is a smallest _bad_ $n$, then the previous number $n-1$ has to be _good_ and we have a contradiction (this is how induction works).
But I agree that infinite descent is more related to proving by contradiction. And in my opinion it's sometimes the most natural way of phrasing things (the closest to how one could arrive at the result independently).

Comment: @user253751 To reiterate Michał Miśkiewicz's comment, I
think an example would be to suppose that, for all $n<N$, $n$ is not the denominator of a fraction equal to $\sqrt{2}$. Then use descent to show that if $N$ were the denominator of such a fraction, some $n<N$ would also be. The induction hypothesis then implies that $N$ is not such a denominator. Assuming the base case can be proved, this gives the result.

Comment: @user253751 It relies on the same well-ordering axiom of positive integers, just in a slightly different form. Any proof by induction you can invent can be automatically rewritten as a proof by infinite descent and vice versa. You just take a slightly different point of view on the very same things, that's all.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your views,  this is how I thought, in infinite descent method , we don't prove the initial case , we assume completely opposite result  and we use the same approach infinitely many times to find smaller integers satisfying the result , cannot we consider this as extremely opposite to the approach we have in mathematical induction?

Comment: @JanakaRodrigo In my example above I should have pointed out that the base case is vacuous: if $N=1$ then it is immediate that there are no such positive integer denominators $n$ with $n<N$. This always happens when you convert an infinite-descent proof into an inductive proof. This may be the reason why it seems that the "initial case" isn't there.

Comment: @fedja could you please mention couple of examples ?

Comment: @JanakaRodrigo Just giveme some proof in one form and I'll show how to recast it into the other one.